# how to pass credentials of a URL to bitsadmin command for downloading a file from the URL

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface, sonatype

I am new to windows scripting, I need to download a file from Sonatype Nexus repository, using "bitsadmin" command. I have tried " bitsadmin  /transfer mydownloadjob  /download  /priority normal http://repolocation/filename.txt C:\tmp\filename.txt " command in my command prompt. I am getting error. the reason may be because I didn't pass credentials for the repository. can you please provide me a way to pass credentials to the command, so that I can access the URL and download the file from  command line (for example, take username and password for accessing http://repolocation/filename.txt are admin and mypwd respectively). FYI, I am able to download file from a URL, which doesn't have any authentication, with the same command

Comment: you need to create a job and then use `/setcredentials` over it

Answer (score 1):

To use bitsadmin with credentials you need to create a job and then use /setcredentials [over it](http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html).Then you'll need check the status of the job to see if it is done.

Though I would recommend you to use [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) (if the file is not too big):

```
call winhhtpjs.bat https://somenexys.com/files/some.jar -saveTo c:\somefile.zip -user the_user -pass some_pass
```

As I think it's easier for use.Though you might need to add your own authentication headers.